# Show a single instance

Tags: django

I know that if I have a model I can create a view that render single instances of the model using a view  like this:

```
def detail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Procedimiento,id=id)
    context = {
        'title':instance.name,
        'instance':instance,
    }
    return render(request,'detail.html',context)
```

but I can not find out how to create a single view that render single instances of an app with several models.

Any help is useful.

Comment: Do you want you view to lookup models dynamically based on urls?

Comment: You need a `models.py`, `an html file` that renders your desired models but this must be stored in a `templates\app_name` inside your `app_name` directory. You also need a `urls.py`. I'm not really sure what you need. Better check the [django documentation website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) for more information

Comment: How is what you want different from what you have shown here already?